# Swift: how to retrieve data from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My structure in firebase is as follows:

```
app name
   user ID
      wins = 7
      losses = 8
```

and my code to read the wins child node

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child(passUserID)
ref?.child("wins").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

     //Convert the info of the data into a string variable
     let getData = snapshot.value as? String
          print(getData)
})
```

But it prints nothing.

Comment: Because "wins" doesn't have any child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read data from Firebase you attach a listener to a path which is what creates a FIRDatabase reference. A FIRDatabaseReference represents a particular location in your Firebase Database where there is a key-value pair list of children. So in your case, you have created a Firebase reference to the key "wins" which only points to a value and not a key-value pair. Your reference was valid up to this point:

```
    ref = Database.database().reference().child(passUserID) 

    //did you mean FIRDatabase and not Database??
```

This FIRDatabaseReference points to the key passUserID which has a key-value pair list of children ["wins":"7"] and ["losses":"8"] (NOTE: a key is always a string). So from your FIRDatabase reference, you create your observer as follows and read the value of "wins":

```
   ref?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    //Convert the info of the data into a string variable
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {

        print(getData)

        let wins = getData["wins"] as? String

        print("\(wins)")

    }

})
```

The Child added event will fire off once per existing piece of data, the snapshot value will be an individual record rather than the entire list like you would get with the value event. As more items come in, this event will fire off with each item. So if "losses" is the first record you might not get the value of "wins". Is this what you are trying to achieve? If what you really wanted to know is the value of "wins" at that particular location and to know if this value has ever changed you should use the .value observer as follows:

```
    ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //Convert the info of the data into a string variable
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {

        let wins = getData["wins"] as? String

        print("\(wins)") //check the value of wins is correct

    }

})
```

Or if you just wanted to get the know the value of wins just once and you are not worried about knowing if there any changes to it, use the "observeSingleEvent" instead of "observe".

**EDIT**

I saw your image and now realize you might also have a problem with your reference. Your ref should actually be something like:

```
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("game-").child(passUserID)
```

You have obscured what "game" is but a valid reference to "wins" will include it.

**SECOND EDIT**

I will add the following so you can properly debug the problem. Use this pattern to observe the value and see if you get an error returned and what is says:

```
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

             print(snapshot)

        }, withCancel: { (error) in

            print(error.localizedDescription)

        })
```

Normally it will give you an error if you cannot access that Firebase location because of a database rule. It will also be a good idea to see if print(snapshot) returns anything as above.

Comment: I am trying to make a statistics page that shows wins/losses and will increment their values as the game is being played so I believe I'd use the second code portion. I tested both of the code and it is still returning me with nothing. I tried setting a label to some gibberish above the print("wins") option to see if it ever reaches that line but it does not. This means the problem is with my reference? But I fixed my reference to be appname.passUserID like stated. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Just a thought, do you have any Firebase database rules? If you do, could you set them all to public access and if you can get a value returned the problem might not even be the code.

Comment: I have added another way to observe the value that will give you the error reported and why it is not giving you a value in my second edit. Also take note of print(snapshot). Hopefully this will allow you to debug and find the problem.

Comment: Take note of this reference   ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(appName).child(passUserID), make sure appName and passUserID are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help. my database rules were not public. I changed them to be accessible to all. Upon running the program this is what I received back: Snap (LOWty9aHdwRnJvsIYuF6tNFor3P2) <null>. The LOWty...thing is my user ID. So it is going in the first statement, which means it is able to access it without error. It appears that my reference is right but when it gets to accessing "losses" or "wins" it retrieves nothing and comes back as null.

Comment: I also did this: FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(appName).child(pass‌​UserID).child("losses") to see what I got and I still got null.

Comment: I got this for the above: Snap (losses) <null>. I have a feeling I am messing up the reference in some way but I am double checking everything.

Comment: Ok. At least it's been confirmed the database rules were holding you back. The second edit I wrote was just for debugging. Now you should do everything I mentioned before the edits I made. Use FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(appName).child(pass‌​‌​UserID) for ref and implement the observe(.value) the way I wrote it exactly. It should work.

Comment: Do this with the ref I mentioned: ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //Convert the info of the data into a string variable
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {

        let wins = getData["wins"] as? String

        print("\(wins)") //check the value of wins is correct

    }

})

Comment: it is still not returning anything. Am I neglecting something minor? My code is as follows: http://imgur.com/QIUJS9t

Comment: Yeah. I see the error now. When you make a firebase reference you do not have to include the app name. FIRDatabase.database().reference() is actually equal to your app name. So all you need to do for your ref is this  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(pass‌​‌​UserID).

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks for all the help! You're the best.

Comment: Great stuff. On a sidenote (because it might become a problem further down the road) please read Firebase guide  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data. The best practice structure for users is users/user-id so in future your ref should look something like FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").(passUserId). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
    ref.child("YOUR_TOP_MOST_KEY").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let keySnapshot = snapshot.key
        //print(keySnapshot)
        self.ref.child(keySnapshot).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot2) in
        //print(snapshot2)
        }) { (error) in
            print("error###\(error)")

        }

    })
```

Comment: What should be in the top most key field? I have tried it with both the app name and with the user ID but it is still returning nothing.

Comment: try to write -game- something text you hide in the picture.

Comment: yeah I did that but it still appears to not be working. I think the problem is with my original reference. I edited it to what the other user suggested but it still does not work.